# Execution of postgresql by a user with administrative permissions is not permitted

Tags: windows, postgresql

Win7. Postgres 9.3.

Every time I type "postgres" in cmd I get this error.

Created a new account without any admin rights and with "Log on as" rights and with correct directory access rights to postgres/data, then I set this account as the "Log on as" in the services menu, but I still get the same error.

update2017: I never found a solution to this.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 12):

For windows do this:

1. Start cmd.exe (administrator as you are)
2. Add postgres user:
   `net user postgres your_password /add`
3. Start a cmd.exe using your new postgres account:
   `runas /user:postgres cmd.exe`
4. You can validate you are login correctly using" `whoami`
5. Run postgres normally.

Comment: Postgres should be started through `pg_ctl` **not** through `postgres.exe`

Answer (score 5):

It is not clear from your question whether you are trying to start the Postgres *service* or "manually" start Postgres without having a Windows service registered.

Since 9.x Postgres does not require it's own Windows user account to run the service. It defaults to use the built-in "Network" account.

To start the Postgres service (if it has been correctly installed), simply use use

```
net start postgresql-9.3
```

(the actual name might be different)

If you did not register a Windows service you should start Postgres through `pg_ctl.exe` not through `postgres.exe`. `pg_ctl.exe` will drop any administrative privileges from the process when starting the server.

To start Postgres manually from the commandline use:

```
pg_ctl -w -D c:\Path\To\The\DataDirectory
```

assuming that the access rights to the data directory are setup correctly so that the current user has full access to the directory.

If you want to install/create the Windows service manually, you can also do this through the `pg_ctl` program:

```
pg_ctl register -N "postgresql-9.3" -D c:\Path\To\The\DataDirectory
```

Again the access rights to the data directory must be setup correctly.

Comment: How can I check whether these access rights are set up properly? And if not, how do I change them?